# How can I use sudo podman to run a container from current user image store

Tags: podman

I'm trying to run a locally built container using podman as root. Note this is purely for a development environment, and I'm aware that running containers as root is bad.

i.e.

```
sudo podman run -it <image>
```

However since the image exists under ~/.local for the current user podman fails to see find it.

So I tried pointing podman at the users container storage area

```
sudo podman run -it <image> --root /home/<username>/.local/share/containers/storage
```

This fails

```
Error: error creating libpod runtime: database libpod temporary files directory (tmpdir) "/run/user/1000/libpod/tmp" does not match our libpod temporary files directory (tmpdir) "/var/run/libpod": database configuration mismatch
```

So I tried again,

```
sudo podman run -it <image> \
   --root /home/<username>/.local/share/containers/storage \
   --tmpdir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp \
   --runroot /run/user/1000
```

This actually works but causes files to be left behind in which only root can access. This means subsequent calls to non-sudo podman fail.

My other workaround consisted of transferring the image from the user to root before running

```
podman save <image> | sudo podman load
sudo podman run <image>
```

Comment: If you would like to share the same container image storage between users,  read-only container image stores: `additionalimagestores` might be useful  (See https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/image-stores-podman) .

Comment: @ErikSjölund Fantastic, thank you, appears to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root user uses the configuration `/etc/containers/storage.conf`, this can be amended to include the non-root users image store. See https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/image-stores-podman

```
additionalimagestores = [
"/home/<username>/.local/share/containers/storage"
]
```

Credit to @ErikSjölund for pointing this out.